# For overhead light fixtures, does it matter which wire is hot or neutral?

Tags: electrical, wiring

There is apparently a specific method to wiring an [American Light Bulb socket](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2xXzIFeB78&t=350s)

> It's important that we get the right strand to the right screw, so you're going to have one side that's perfectly smooth and the smooth side is going to go to the brass. That's your hot side. The neutral side going to the silver is ribbed. So I'm going to put a little bend in each of the sides here and we're going to screw it down.

I'm trying to write an overhead light fixture which just has two wires coming out of it. Does it matter which one is hot and neutral?

For my light fixture, one wire is red and one wire is blue. For the ceiling they're both white.

Comment: For the light itself, it does not matter.  For safety you will want the hot far away from fingers, so usually the centre post is use for hot, instead of the outside ring of metal close to fingers.

Comment: I think you are just putting colours to wires in the question, instead of stating what is there.  In Americas you usually find wire in cable to be black(hot) and white(neutral), not two white wires.

Comment: Two white wires from the ceiling? In the US? Someone screwed up somewhere. You have a bigger problem.

Comment: I think it was just a very old copper wiring job. Potentially from the 1950s when the house was built.

Comment: Is the wire stranded or solid? If stranded, then someone probably used some lamp cord inappropriately and you should find the other end.

Comment: The two wires in the ceiling may both be white simply because they got painted. It's a common practice to spray paint a new house but it's not common to mask the electrical boxes. The wires inside the box end up getting painted too - often in white, since that's a common color for ceilings.

Comment: I agree with Greg+ however in a light fixture box there are possibilities depending on how many cables enter the box if only 1 cable 3 conductors  then the neutral goes to silver, the colored wire goes to brass(some places use blue as the neutral the U.S. uses white &sometimes gray)green or bare copper should always be ground, other than that all the other colors are usually hot go to brass screw
If there more cables entering the box there is a likelihood that a white could be hot going to a switch, but the switched hot should be a colored wire returning black or red, invest in a tic tester

Comment: Both wires are solid, however they may have both been painted. I mean, sprayed. They must have sprayed the crap out of them though, I think the right answer here is the one @crip659. I guess the convention is to make hot the center point on a bulb when in a lamp, but in a ceiling light they assume you're not likely to touch the fixture so it doesn't matter at all. But I assume I could have hooked up a meter to the center point on the installed fixture to find out which cable should have been hot.

Comment: The white-white is probably a *switch loop* that was mis-wired with white for the switched-hot.  This is reason #3 why that is bad.   It should be rearranged to be correct.   Also where did this lamp come from that it has wrong color wires?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box in question please?

Comment: It sounds like you've managed to find a reasonably serious wiring issue in your house. Pics of the wiring (as TPE asked for) and pics of the lamp in question's wires will help us help you get the wiring straightened out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convention in the video is to make hot the center point on the bulb's outlet (what you screw the bulb into). In the graph below this is called the "foot contact". When in a lamp, there is more value because your fingers are some what likely to come into contact with the outlet on the "base" part. If the "base" was hot you'd shock yourself. Not all ceiling fixtures differentiate though. You could hook a meter up to it to find which wire the center point corresponds to for correctness. But it probably doesn't matter.

[image: Parts of the Light Bulb]

Comment: This actually answers the question asked. Harper's answer addresses the potentially serious miswiring part that wasn't explicitly asked.

Comment: Which is why more modern fixtures include a ground wire, to guarantee that the fixture itself, including any metal socket parts, remains safe to touch.

Answer (score 4):

Your switch wiring is incorrect.  This is the root of the problem.

Your switch is wired with an old-school "switch loop". Power comes into the lamp.  A spur goes down to the switch with "always-hot" and back as "switched-hot" for the lamp.  Neutral is not present on the switch loop.

Code requires that the white wire be used as the "always-hot". (for several reasons).  Which means, up in the lamp, the white switch-loop wire must be connected to the black supply wire.

The previous installer took a shortcut, and just connected black-black, resulting in your not being able to identify the neutral wire.